# How to Call Application service from Web Api in ASP.Net Boilerplate MVC project?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

ASP.NET Boilerplate (.Net Framework v4.7.2 & MVC)

I am creating a web api controller(AgentInfoController) for an application service class(AgentInfoAppService), which depends on a repository IAgentInfoRepository. From AgentInfoController, I am able to call a method from AgentInfoAppService by passing IAgentInfoRepository in the constructor  like this `new AgentInfoAppService(_agentInfoRepository).GetAgentCampaignswithCode` but I am not sure if this is the correct way?

We have a working code from mvc layer where we call application service class(dynamic web api layer) without adding any references to Repository like below. Is there a way we could add a dependency injection so I don't have to add the repository in each application service calls from web api layer?Please advise.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/api/services/app/AgentInfoAppService/GetAgentCampaignswithCode?agentCode=100",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})

public class AgentInfoAppService : ApplicationService, IAgentInfoAppService
{
    private readonly IAgentInfoRepository _agentInfoRepository;

    public AgentInfoAppService(IAgentInfoRepository agentInfoRepository)
    {
        _agentInfoRepository = agentInfoRepository;
    }

     public GetAgentCodeCampaignOutput GetAgentCampaignswithCode(string agentCode, bool? defaultCampaign)
    {
        var agentCampaigns = _agentInfoRepository.GetAgentCampaignswithCode(agentCode, defaultCampaign);
        return new GetAgentCodeCampaignOutput()
        {
            AgentCodeCampaign = Mapper.Map<List<AgentCodeCampaignDto>>(agentCampaigns)
        };
    }
}

 public class AgentInfoController : AbpApiController
{

    private readonly IAgentInfoRepository _agentInfoRepository;

    [HttpGet]
    public GetAgentCodeCampaignOutput GetAgentCampaignswithCode(string agentCode, bool? defaultCampaign)
    {
        return new AgentInfoAppService(_agentInfoRepository).GetAgentCampaignswithCode(agentCode, defaultCampaign);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the project `Abp` creates all Methods from `ApplicationService` layer and you can use it. You don't need to create the method again in the controller.

Here is an example of what I'm saying

I have an `ApplicationServie` method like this

```
public class CiudadAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<AdozonaCiudad, CiudadDto, int, PagedAndSortedRequest, CiudadDto, CiudadDto>, ICiudadAppService
{

    private readonly ICiudadManager _ciudadManager;
    public CiudadAppService(IRepository<AdozonaCiudad> repository, ICiudadManager ciudadManager) : base(repository)
    {
        _ciudadManager = ciudadManager;
    }

    public override async Task<CiudadDto> CreateAsync(CiudadDto input)
    {

        var result = await _ciudadManager.RegistrarOActualizar(ObjectMapper.Map<AdozonaCiudad>(input));

        return MapToEntityDto(result);
    }
}
```

In this `AppService` I have one Method called `CreateAsync` this method can be used from javascript like this.

```
(function ($) {

var _ciudadService = abp.services.app.ciudad;
var _$form = $('form[name=Index]');

function save() {

    _$form.validate({
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var firstInvalidElement = $(validator.errorList[0].element);
                $('html,body').scrollTop(firstInvalidElement.offset().top - 100);
                firstInvalidElement.focus();
            }
        },

        rules: {
            Ciudad: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            Ciudad: "El valor del campo es requerido"
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass('error-validation')
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass('error-validation')
        }
    });

    if (!_$form.valid()) {
        return;
    }

    var ciudad = _$form.serializeFormToObject(); //serializeFormToObject is defined in main.js

    abp.ui.setBusy(_$form);
    _ciudadService.create(ciudad).done(function () {
        location.reload(true); //reload page to see edited role!
        abp.notify.success('Registro correcto');
        $(".save-button").html('Guardar');
    }).always(function () {
        abp.ui.clearBusy(_$form);
    });
}
}
```

As you can see there the important part is: `var _ciudadService = abp.services.app.ciudad;` with this you're creating a service and you can access to all the methods that you have in `ApplicationService`

I hope it could help you, if you need further help please leave a comment!

Comment: Thanks Jose for the response. I understand Abp creates the dynamic web api layer for application service classes. We are planning to host the web api project separately in IIS, so I was not sure if we would still be able to call those application service classes from  api. Let me test it and get back to you.

Comment: Ooh, understood, I had the same question even I have created an issue on GitHub, follow it here:
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5476

Comment: Sorry, it took a while. I am able to host the web api and call the application service from api. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoséPolanco how can i call this api in postman